# How to use different js file instead of writing in HTML for express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to deploy the simple express application but I am stuck at a weird problem that I don't know how to solve. The problem is when I am writing the inline script in HTML file it is working perfectly fine but after using other js file instead of writing inline the `Unexpected token: '<'`  error occurs.

**This is working**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      const ws = new WebSocket("wss://obscure-oasis-50326.herokuapp.com/")
      let ws = new WebSocket(HOST);
      let el;

      ws.onmessage = (event) => {
        el = document.getElementById('server-time');
        el.innerHTML = 'Server time: ' + event.data;
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="server-time"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is not**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="server-time"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { Server } = require('ws');
const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = '/index.html';


const server = express()
  .use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname }))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));


const wss = new Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  console.log('Client connected');
  ws.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
});

setInterval(() => {
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(new Date().toTimeString());
  });
}, 1000);
```

The main.js is not static so, there is no point of using `express.static()` (Please correct me if I am wrong).

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express isn't serving the main.js file, only index.html.

Try changing lines 9-11 to this:

```
const server = express()
  .use(express.static('./'))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
```